# Should I use trim() before inserting mysql data?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I do this before inserting an email address:

```
$email = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']));
```

I'm switching to PDO, so I know I don't need to do `mysqli_real_escape_string` anymore, but can I also ditch the trim() part, or does it not hurt to still do that before inserting via PDO?

The thinking was just to trim any whitespace in case the user hit space by accident at the beginning or end.

I also realize that maybe trim() wasn't necessary to begin with?  I feel like I don't see it much in other people's code so maybe it's flawed thinking on my part?

Comment: Depends, do you want leading or trailing white space in your record? If not, continue to use `trim()`.

Comment: `I don't need to do mysqli_real_escape_string anymore` That depends on whether you're using it correctly as to whether you need something instead.

Comment: It _is_ necessary, if you don’t want to store any leading/trailing whitespace the user might enter before/after their actual email address (be it on purpose or accidental) into your database. But it should have happened the other way around to begin with - trimming of the value first, escaping the result for use in a MySQL query second.

Comment: *"before inserting using PDO?"* - Um... you're using a `mysqli_` function here. I'm wondering about which api is used to connect with also.

Comment: @ -Fred -ii-  Hence, "I used to do this before"

Comment: Fair enough, will do, thank you!

Comment: @user3304303 ok my bad. I misread. Sorry. Edit: I did fix a typo though, you had PDF lol It should have been PDO.

Comment: @user3304303 You are connecting with PDO though, right? and not mixing different apis, I had to ask. Your *"I'm switching to PDO, so I know I don't need to do mysqli_real_escape_string anymore"* suggests that you may be mixing different apis, it's a tad unclear (to me).

Comment: Sorry, I just mean that when I used "regular" mysqli to insert data into database, I would use that real_escape_string function to sanitize user input.  I'm going through all my code and changing all queries to use PDO now, and everything I've read said I don't need to do any escaping at all. So I won't use mysqli_real_escape_string once all queries are changed to PDO.  Just curious if I should still use trim() or if that's unnecessary to do regardless of whether I used mysqli or PDO. I probably just confused you more.  But based on other comments, I will still use trim(). Thx for typo fix!